# Azure IoT Hub - How to use Table Storage in IoT Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-iot-hub, azure-blob-storage

<del>First of all, sorry for my english skill.</del>

I'm a high school student from South Korea who's doing project with Azure IoT Hub.

I am working on a project where a raspberry pi device is sending values to an Azure IoT Hub. I would like to save this data in Azure Table Storage as this data will be used by some other services (Azure WebApp for example).

So I tried to save raspberry pi values in Azure Table Storage.
But when I add endpoints of IoT Hub, I just can use only blob storage container

[image: when i pick container]

[image: this is my storage created before, no any other setting, just default]

[image: when i choose, default is blob and i can't change endpoints to table storage.]

of course i still don't understand about iot hub
please don't look so bad.

---

In a nutshell

1. I want to send raspberry pi values to Azure Table Storage and not Blob Storage however only option available to me is Blob Storage when I am setting endpoints for Azure IoT Hub.
2. How to send values to Table Storage via Azure IoT Hub.

by any chance, my logic for Azure is completely wrong?

Comment: Good Morning DolXeGoD, did you find a way to send your IoT data direct into a table storage? For visualization I want to use PowerBI but a query from BlobStorage takes PowerBI huge time. I speak from around one hour for 3MB and that is not acceptable. thank you for your respond, best wishes from Austria,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way how to store D2C messages in the Azure Store Table is using an Azure EventHubTrigger Function.

More details about the function and its integration with Azure IoT Hub can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d383f085-b540-4cf5-8835-add19f4ed7b2/need-doc-to-guide-to-save-iot-device-messages-to-azure-storage-table?forum=azureiothub).

Answer (score 3):

You can use either functions or Azure Stream Analytics to push hub data to Azure table storage. I found Stream Analytics worked best for me as I was better able to format the data.

Comment: thx for answer although my vague question !!
:D
I gonna find more documentation about Stream Analytics

Answer (score 2):

IoT Hub natively supports routing messages to Azure storage as blobs. Refer [Save IoT hub messages that contain sensor data to your Azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-store-data-in-azure-table-storage).
There does, however, seem to be a typo in the doc where it lists ‘table storage’ instead of 'blob storage'. We’ll get those typos corrected.

Comment: thanks for your kindness answer, but i even know IoT hub's default storage is only blob storage. 
but i must route to table storage for my project. and then i found route to table storage is be not impossible. this is why I question here.

Comment: This does not answer the question